# DirectShow video playback fails for MP4 file, not for AVI file

Tags: c++, video, directshow

I am trying to play a video using DirectShow. For testing I have here two files, one AVI, one MP4. Both files contain a single H264 video stream, and both files play back perfectly using `IGraphBuilder::RenderFile`. Unfortunately, the files will not necessarily be stored locally when deployed. So I replaced the call to `RenderFile` with this snippet (plus error handling):

```
graphBuilder->AddSourceFilter(file, NULL, &sourceFilter);
sourceFilter->FindPin(L"Output", &outputPin);
graphBuilder->Render(outputPin);
```

This works for both local files and remote files using HTTP. But only for the AVI file. The MP4 file fails to play back.

According to the MSDN documentation `AddSourceFilter` and `Render` should automagically add filters as needed, which I expected to work, especially since `RenderFile` manages to do it.

Does anyone have any idea why this doesn't work, and, more importantly, how to fix it?

**EDIT**

The filter graph produced by `RenderFile` for AVI is exactly the same as the one produced by `Render`. For the MP4 on the other hand `Render` adds an audio path, even though the file contains no audio stream.

```
MP4 RenderFile
---------------------------- 
Video Renderer
FSL MX53 VPU Decoder Filter
FSL MP4 Parser
\FlashDisk\video.mp4

MP4 Render
----------------------------
Video Renderer
FSL AAC Plus Decoder Filter
Audio Renderer
FSL MX53 VPU Decoder Filter
FSL MP4 Parser
\FlashDisk\video.mp4
```

Comment: There is no stock source filter for `.MP4`, you need to install third party filter first to have it supported. E.g. [these](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/mpeg4/).

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. The errors originally mentioned were indeed caused by a missing parser on my local system. The failure on the target system looked the same, but has a different cause. I have updated the question accordingly.